# Daikon failing to run: "Error at line 1 in file example.dtrace: No declaration was provided for program point program.point:::POINT"

Tags: invariants, dynamic-analysis

I am attempting to run Daikon on a .decls and .dtrace file I generated from a CSV file using an open-source perl script. The .decls and .dtrace file will be provided below. The daikon.jar file is held within a directory, which has a sub-directory "scripts" where I keep the .dtrace and .decls.

I am attempting to call daikon using the following command from within the directory containing the daikon.jar file:

java -cp daikon.jar daikon.Daikon scripts/example.dtrace scripts/example.decls

The program response is the following:

```
Daikon version 5.8.10, released November 1, 2021; http://plse.cs.washington.edu/daikon.
(read 1 decls file)                                                            
Processing trace data; reading 1 dtrace file:                                  

Error at line 1 in file scripts/example.dtrace: No declaration was provided for program point program.point:::POINT
```

I am confused as to why it can't find the declarations file I provided which contains the declaration for the program.point function. Below I have provided the contents of both the example.dtrace and the example.decls files.

---

**example.dtrace**

```
program.point:::POINT
a
1
1
b
1
1
c
2
1
d
2
1
e
4
1

aprogram.point:::POINT
a
3
1
b
3
1
c
4
1
d
4
1
e
5
1
```

---

**example.decls**

```
DECLARE
aprogram.point:::POINT
a
double
double
1
b
double
double
1
c
double
double
1
d
double
double
1
e
double
double
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `example.decls` file declares a program point named **a**program.point:::POINT, which starts with an a.  Your `example.dtrace` file contains samples for a program point named program.point:::POINT, which does not start with an a.

So, the message is right:  there is no declaration for a program point named program.point:::POINT, though there is a declaration for a program point named **a**program.point:::POINT.

Making the program point names consistent between the two files should resolve your problem.  By adding the character `a` to the beginning of your `example.dtrace` file, I was able to get Daikon to produce output:

```
Daikon version 5.8.11, released November 2, 2021; http://plse.cs.washington.edu/daikon.
(read 1 decls file)
Processing trace data; reading 1 dtrace file:
[2021-11-17T10:13:50.284232]: Finished reading example.dtrace                  
===========================================================================
aprogram.point:::POINT
a == b
c == d
a one of { 1.0, 3.0 }
c one of { 2.0, 4.0 }
e one of { 4.0, 5.0 }
Exiting Daikon.
```